# Mongodb MMS Btree chart

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-mms

I have to monitor mongodb instance and I have trouble understanding Btree graph.As I understand from the docs Btree graph gives information about the indexes utilized for db operations, shows number of times the indexes were loaded in memory(hits), number of times it failed to load the indexes in the memory(misses).

how do we know how much capacity we have left? If we are close to running out of memory to cover all indexes, how to get an update before it happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the MongoDB MMS docs:

> B-tree
>
> These alert conditions refer to the metrics found on the host’s btree
>   chart. To view the chart, see Accessing a Host’s Statistics.
>
> B-tree: accesses is
>
> ```
> Sends an alert if the number of accesses to B-tree indexes meets the specified average.
> ```
>
> B-tree: hits is
>
> ```
> Sends an alert if the number of times a B-tree page was in memory meets the specified average.
> ```
>
> B-tree: misses is
>
> ```
> Sends an alert if the number of times a B-tree page was not in memory meets the specified average.
> ```

So if you configure the alert condition B-tree 'misses' , an alert will be sounded if the page was not in memory for the specified average, once this alert is sounded you can allocated additional RAM. How much additional RAM to allocate depends on the number of documents being inserted, size of documents and number of indexes.

Comment: thanks a lot, I'll try adding alerts and check for discrepancies.